# What to do when a helpful answerer is helping the questioner hang themselves?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

Let us stipulate that there is a Service Provider, Heroku, that provides a Service, "App Hosting". Let us refer to this Service to as "The Rope".

Let us further stipulate that there is a manner of using the service (i.e., "The Rope") that the Service Provider suggests is "bad". Let us stipulate that this manner is referred to as "Hanging Oneself". And, in this particular instance, "Hanging Oneself" is specifically in reference to (a) developing in SQLite and (b) deploying in PostgreSQL. Let us assume that "Hanging Oneself" is "bad" because one ends up "dead" or "in great pain".

Now, suppose an Inquisitive SO Asker asks the question, "Using the Rope, how may I Hang Myself?" As, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691021/when-i-deploy-my-rails-app-on-heroku-the-step-verifying-deploy-wont-stop-an/35691430#35691430). And a Helpful SO Answerer says, "Here is precisely how to Hang Oneself using The Rope."

Let us assume that the Helpful SO Answerer is **exactly correct** in how one may use The Rope to Hang Oneself.

One the one hand, the Helpful SO Answerer is super-helpful, because the Inquisitive SO Asker can now successfully go about Hanging Themselves.

On the other hand, the Inquisitive SO Asker is likely to end up "dead" or "in great pain".

What to do?

EDIT:

Following the comments, I'm sorry that I was obtuse. I guess what I'm struggling with is that the accepted answer is in direct contradiction to what Heroku says, and yet the answer was accepted. So, presumably, the person who asked the question is now going to go off and do what Heroku suggests not to do. And that sort of bothers me. I guess I should let it go.

Comment: Thanks, @davidism, my first time. I'll try to be less obtuse in the future.

Comment: Don't wait until the future, you can edit the post to be clearer now. "What to do?" Leave a comment, or downvote if you want.

Comment: Did you link to the wrong answer? The one you've linked to seems to be telling OP *not* to use different database engines in development and production.

Comment: @Rob - The answer that I provided was the "don't do it" answer. The answer that was accepted was the "here's how to hang yourself" answer. I guess that's my frustration: the accepted answer is bad (in my opinion) for the original poster. And yet, there's no way to keep the original poster from hurting themselves. I guess it's stupid for me to obsess.

Comment: Contrary to davidism, I thought it was a great read.

Comment: Thanks, @JoshCaswell, I'm feeling kind of crap about this, now. But, hey. Bruises are learning.

Comment: You can write an answer explaining the right thing to do, and why. But at some point, you need to let it go -- users will do what users will do. (Unless there are direct security implications. In that case, feel free to burn the world to the ground to kill the post.) It doesn't seem to apply here, but users frequently have awkward reasons ("my boss said so") that they *need* to do something in a weird way. For that reason, I usually prefer to provide an answer that explains both (a) what they *should* be doing and why, & (b) how to do what they actually asked in the least harmful way possible.

Comment: Meta downvotes are a lot less meaningful than main-site downvotes. Please don't let them bother you too much. You could probably be a bit more clear next time, but you're still as likely as not to be randomly downvoted by someone who feels like they already had this discussion four years ago *so why didn't you just say your piece then?!*.

Comment: Downvote, comment, do whatever you can to improve the value of the post. It's the same case as someone offering SQL query that's vulnerable to injection attack. **The accepted answer doesn't mean the best answer**, it's only an indicator that it helps OP.